# Using read.table to read a CSV file gives a table with quotes

Tags: r, csv, read.table

I am trying to read a csv file in R using the `read.table` command and the table I get in R has double quotes around every entry. The problem is that I cannot use these entries with quotes to do mathematical operations.

Here is my read command:

```
exprs_data <- as.matrix(read.table("Test1.csv",
     sep= ",",header=TRUE,row.names=1,as.is=TRUE))##
```

Here is the imported table in R:

```
ABC DEF XYZ 
m0122 " 854"    "1487"  "1855"
m0152 "  97"    " 159"  " 468"
m0257 " 157"    " 733"  "   6"
```

Why are there quotes around numbers?? I never experienced this problem in R before. Can anybody help me importing this csv file in R?

Comment: can you show the results of `str(exprs_data)` ?

Comment: Hi ben, here is the result of str(exprs_data) for original file:  chr [1:4, 1:22] "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "NEW" "m0122" "m0152" "m0257" "m0427" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "m0122" "m0152" "m0257" "m0427"
  ..$ : chr [1:22] "annotation" "Annotation2" "Generic_name" "Name" ...

Comment: what if you omit `as.matrix()` ? coercing a data frame with any non-numeric columns will give you a matrix of character (as you got).

Comment: Ben, Removing as.matrix fixes the problem. Please see my response below. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes indicate that the values in your matrix are strings rather than numbers. Without knowing what your csv file looks like, I suspect some value in the file is not a valid number,  and with the conversion to a matrix (your `as.matrix`) statement, everything is converted to strings to comply with the required structure of the matrix (needs to be all the same data type). I'm not entirely sure why you are doing the matrix conversion but you can explicitly specify in `read.table` what type the data is by using the `colClasses` parameter. Try this (assuming all columns are to be treated as numbers, otherwise use a vector of different values for each column in `colClasses`):

```
exprs_data <- read.table("Test1.csv", sep= ",", header=TRUE, 
                         row.names=1, colClasses = "numeric")
```

You can convert it to a matrix if you want but you could also work directly with the data frame that `read.table` returns. As mentioned in the comment, you can get details on the structure (including column data types) of your variable by running `str(exprs_data)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Removing 'as.matrix' fixes the problem. It was in mt read command by default as 'heatmap2' package requires a numeric matrix. Now I read the file, extract the numeric columns and convert to matrix.